# QOpenGLContext usage without QApplication or QGuiApplication. Only QCoreApplication

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm trying to unit test some code that relies standard opengl operations such as shader compiling, buffer creation and shader binding . My issue is our automated system that runs the test only has access to QCoreApplication. As such, whenever I use my unit tests with QApplication or QGuiApplication it all works fine but using it with QCoreApplication, nothing works. Does anybody know if it's possible to get OpenGL running with QCoreApplication.

The simple setup is below for reference

```
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts);
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DontCheckOpenGLContextThreadAffinity);
    _app = std::make_shared<QApplication>(argc, nullptr);
    
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setMajorVersion(3);
format.setMinorVersion(0);

context = std::make_shared<QOpenGLContext>();
context->setFormat(format);
context->create();

surface = std::make_shared<QOffscreenSurface>();
surface->create();
std::cout << "Open Gl Surface: " << surface->isValid() << "\n";

context->makeCurrent(surface.get());
```